# Issues with django Models.py

Tags: python, mysql, django

> I am facing some problems with **model.py** file

the code of model.py is:

```
from django.db import models

import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
 def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
 def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
 def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

when i am run this command **python manage.py shell** the following error occurs

```
File "/home/ghrix/testing/demo/polls/models.py", line 9
    def __unicode__(self):
                         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

this error occur after i add some lines of code in my model.py file

> import datetime from django.utils import timezone

**In Poll class**

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
 def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

**In Choice class**

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

Comment: After your add a new line to py, your editor save it back to file, with indent-config by your editor. Old file style not fits your editor's style, so error happens.   Make sure to use only one style of indent:  '\t' or blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is very sensitive to indentation. Your particular code should look like this:

```
from django.db import models

import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

Remember, the suggested indentation is 4 spaces for each level. The problem you're having is that your attributes like say `Poll.question` should be defined at the same level as the method `__unicode__`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code has errors with indents. Try this one:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
  poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
  choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  votes = models.IntegerField()

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.choice
```

The same for class `Pool`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might have mixed spaces with tabs, try run:

```
python -m tabnanny models.py
```

And fix the tabs/spaces indentation error. It's a good idea to *always* use spaces instead of tabs, per [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Use the below file instead. You have indentation problems. Remember all code at the same level should be aligned properly.

You should also make sure you don't mix spaces and tabs in your editor. Generally its better to stick with spaces. The key is to make sure you don't mix and match - otherwise you'll get  similar errors.

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.question)

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.choice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `def __unicode__(self):` is **indented less** than the `question =` and `pub_date =` lines. The `def` should have the same indentation as the rest of the code above it in the class, if it is part of the class.

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    # the def should start at this indent level like the lines above
    # <<<<<<<<
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
```